# Is there any way to fix missing quest NPCs in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I'm currently trying to overcome a game-breaking bug in my Cyberpunk 2077 (PC, Steam) save file that has broken the main quest for me, and was wondering if anyone had found a fix or workaround for these types of bugs in this game, or other ideas I could try. *(Important note: This bug occurred after installing the Day One Patch.)*

### The problem

I'm on the mission ["The Heist"](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/The_Heist), at the objective after you put on the suit where you're supposed to get into Delamain, the car that Dex got for you. The problem is that **Delamain is missing.** Jackie is leaning up against thin air, I can walk right through the spot where Delamain is supposed to be, and I haven't been able to get the interaction prompt for getting into the car to appear, despite the objective marker still showing up and floating in midair. I remember that when I first got here, the car *was* here, but now after doing some sidequests and coming back to it later, it's just gone and I can't get it to reappear.

[image]

Because of this bug, the main quest is broken and I can't continue the game.

### Things I've tried

I have tried:

- **Restarting the game** and reloading the save multiple times.
- **Fast traveling** to different places to "unload" the area, then fast traveling back. This reloaded other objects, but didn't load in the car.
- **Waiting** for several days' worth of in-game time.
- Putting objects and corpses into the area where the car is supposed to be, in the hopes that it would realize the car wasn't there. (No dice.)
- Calling Delamain on the phone.
- Taking off the quest item suit and putting it back on again, to change the objective marker.

None of it worked. I don't have any saves that were long enough ago to fix this, and really don't want to have to restart my game or just do sidequests forever, but it seems I might have no choice. I also really don't want to have to uninstall and reinstall the game, since it's absolutely *huge.*

**Are there any known fixes for an "NPC didn't spawn" bug in the game, and/or potential solutions?**

*(My setup specs, in case it is relevant: PC Steam copy, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, Intel i7, Asus Rog Strix 17 GL703GE.)*

Comment: Can you uninstall the patch (or reinstall the game)? Otherwise, the only thing you really can do is keep playing and return to the main mission at a later time (there might be a scripted event the car needs to get loaded for or something like that).

Comment: @Joachim I'm reluctant to reinstall the game due to its sheer download size (took me a solid day on launch), but if I've exhausted all possibilities, I can try it and see if that fixes it and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [version 1.05](https://www.cyberpunk.net/en/news/37166/hotfix-1-05) of the game, this should no longer happen:

> - Jackie will no longer disappear in The Pickup or The Heist.
> - Fixed issues with Delamain not appearing or doing nothing outside the Afterlife in The Heist.

Comment: I uninstalled the game a while ago so cannot test this as the definitive solution, but I'll checkmark it as hopefully it will show future visitors that this bug has been resolved.